# How to make UIPageViewController with unknown page numbers?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I need to show some media contents on UIPageViewController and allow user to swipe between medias (just like a gallery) and I do not know how many videos or images are ahead because I have to get them one by one from server. How can I use UIPageViewController with unknown page numbers and just knowing previous and next page view controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Collection view like a page view controller. You can try making the collection view cell to fit the screen like a page view controller and Update the data source and collection view as and when required.

You can see a sample [here](https://github.com/pooja-kamath/TMDBMoviesApp) in HomeViewController

Answer (score 0):

For `UIPageViewController` you *do not need* to provide total number of items to make it works. When setting up your `UIPageViewController`, you only need to set the View Controller you want to display when it first loaded by following code:

```
pageViewController.setViewControllers([viewControllerToBeDisplayed], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

And then to enable user to go back and forth, you just need to implement following methods of `UIPageViewControllerDataSource`:

```
public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
```

Hope it helps.